# How can we check postback occur before postback to server by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

- I Want to Show Loading Image during post back.
- When submit event occur it's OK but i want to show for all post back
  event.
- Problem is I need to check post back occur or not before post back
  to server.

**jQuery**

```
$("#form1").live("submit", function () {
    $('#dvLoading').fadeIn(2000);
});

$("#form1").live("click", function () {
    if(  **// here I need to check postback occur or not before postback**) {
        $('#dvLoading').fadeIn(2000);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dvLoading').hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
         <div id="dvLoading">
                <img src="Styles/images/Processing.jpg" />
         </div>
```

Comment: You want to check if the postback occurred, before you post back? Could you elaborate a little on that?

Comment: `$().live` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9 and is horribly slow. Use `$().on`. Also, upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to check if the postback has already occurred in your 'click' handler. You could do this by defining a variable to check if the postback has already occurred.

```
var postbackCalled = false;

$("#form1").live("submit", function () {
    $('#dvLoading').fadeIn(2000);
    postbackCalled = true;
});

$("#form1").live("click", function () {
    if(!postbackCalled) {
        $('#dvLoading').fadeIn(2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: I would like to check web control Autopostback Property In 'click' handler.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET AutoPostBack? Something like this:
`<form runat="server">
<asp:TextBox id="tb1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="TRUE" />
</form>`